# Different schedules for Oracle chain steps

Tags: oracle, schedule, chain

I'm building a job chain in Oracle SQL consisting of multiple steps (1 to 5).
**Steps 1-> 2 -> 3->5** should run one after another, on daily basis. No problem here.
But step 4 should be run once a month, in between **steps 3 and 5**, based on a custom schedule. So that once a month it should be **1 -> 2 -> 3-> 4 -> 5**.

Is there a way to apply different schedules for steps in this chain or what's the best way to do this? So far I only have 2 ideas:

1. Create a separate table for the custom schedule, which step 4 will be checking against each daily run. If the date is present in the table - it performs the action, otherwise does nothing.
2. Create an additional job that runs on these specific dates and creates an event. Step 4 in this case is triggered by the event.

Are these good approaches or this can be done otherwise i the scheduler?

Thanks

Comment: Scheduling each job separately would be good idea as there will be full control.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second solution is a good. Because you can control all process. In addition add a log script to check the steps be done succesfully or what's problem.